# Adding a column to a pandas dataframe based on other columns

Tags: python, pandas, list-comprehension

**Problem description**

*Introductory remark: For the code have a look below*

Let's say we have a pandas dataframe consisting of 3 columns and 2 rows.
I'd like to add a 4th column called 'Max_LF' that will consist of an array. The value of the cell is retrieved by having a look at the column 'Max_WD'. For the first row that would be 0.35 which will than be compared to the values in the column 'WD' where 0.35 can be found at the third position. Therefore, the third value of the column 'LF' should be written into the column 'Max_LF'. If the value of 'Max_WD' occures multiple times in 'WD', then all corresponding items of 'LF' should be written into 'Max_LF'.

**Failed attempt**

So far I had various attemps on first retrieving the index of the item in 'Max_WD' in 'WD'. After potentially retrieving the index the idea was to then get the items of 'LF' via their index:
`df4['temp_indices'] = [i for i, x in enumerate(df4['WD']) if x == df4['Max_WD']]`

However, a ValueError occured:
raise ValueError('Lengths must match to compare')
ValueError: Lengths must match to compare

**This is what the example dateframe looks like**

`df = pd.DataFrame(data={'LF': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]] , 'WD': [[0.28, 0.34, 0.35, 0.18], [0.42, 0.45, 0.45, 0.18], [0.31, 0.21, 0.41, 0.41]], 'Max_WD': [0.35, 0.45, 0.41]})`

**The expected outcome should look like**

`df=pd.DataFrame(data={'LF': [[1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4], [1, 2, 3, 4]] , 'WD': [[0.28, 0.34, 0.35, 0.18], [0.42, 0.45, 0.45, 0.18], [0.31, 0.21, 0.41, 0.41]], 'Max_WD': [0.35, 0.45, 0.41], 'Max_LF': [[3] ,[2,3], [3,4]]})`

Comment: I think your first problem is that it looks like you are trying to make some sort of 3 dimensional Pandas DF. Your question is confusing to follow, I would recommend simplifying it.

Comment: How did you create that DataFrame in the first place? Storing lists in a DataFrame is generally a bad idea, and in this case makes these rather simple manipulations much more difficult than they need to be. If you instead use a MultiIndex this is rather simple and far more efficient.

Comment: The expected outcome example does not really match your description. You say that the new column should contain a list of all the values above the threshold, but the example shows only a scalar value.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could get it by simply using `lambda` as follows

```
df['Max_LF'] = df.apply(lambda x : [i + 1 for i, e in enumerate(x['WD']) if e == x['Max_WD']], axis=1)
```

output is

```
    LF  Max_WD  WD  Max_LF
0   [1, 2, 3]   0.35    [0.28, 0.34, 0.35, 0.18]    [3]
1   [1, 2, 3]   0.45    [0.42, 0.45, 0.45, 0.18]    [2, 3]
2   [1, 2, 3]   0.41    [0.31, 0.21, 0.41, 0.41]    [3, 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys! With your help I was able to solve my problem.
Like Prince Francis suggested I first did

`df['temp'] = df.apply(lambda x : [i for i, e in enumerate(x['WD']) if e == x['Max_WD']], axis=1)`

to get the indicees of the 'WD'-values in 'LF'. In a second stept I then could add the actual column 'Max_LF' by doing

`df['LF_Max'] = df.apply(lambda x: [x['LF'][e] for e in (x['temp'])],axis=1)`

Thanks a lot guys!

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it by [applying a function over axis 1](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.apply.html).

For this, I recommend you to first convert the WD list into a pd.Series (or a numpy.ndarray) and then compare all the values at once.

Assuming that you want a list of all the values higher than the threshold, you could use this:

```
>>> def get_max_wd(x): 
...     wd = pd.Series(x.WD) 
...     return list(wd[wd >= x.Max_WD])
... 
>>> df.apply(get_max_wd, axis=1)
0          [0.35]
1    [0.45, 0.45]
2    [0.41, 0.41]
dtype: object
```

The result of the `apply` can then be assigned as a new column into the dataframe:

```
df['Max_LF'] = df.apply(get_max_wd, axis=1)
```

If what you are after is only the maximum value (see my comment above), you can use the `max()` method within the function.